# Python regex to match any date format

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse a string looking for a valid date format within it. I would use dateutil or datetime libraries, however, they don't support scanning of whole strings (eg "2003-03-29 George M. Holmes Convention Center, Appalachian State University, Boone, NC" won't parse as it is not all related to a date).
The problem is that the string could be in virtually any date format, my goal is to identify and capture it in a group.

So:
"2003-03-29 George M. Holmes Convention Center, Appalachian State University, Boone, NC"
->"2003-03-29"

"DMB Warfield Theatre, San Francisco, CA 5/10/1995" -> "5/10/1995"

"''[[Love You (The Beach Boys album)|Love You]]''
(1977)"
-> 1977

"DMB Warfield Theatre, San Francisco, CA" does not match
Please keep in mind that the date/year could be anywhere in the string and it could also have days, be in mm/dd/yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy, or "MONTH DAY, YEAR" etc.

If there is a library that could do this, I would be very grateful if someone could point it out.

Answer (score 0):

use a group with or pattern = '(format1|format2|

go from the longest format1 to shortest formatn